# Deferred Rendering - Is it valid to reconstruct position for a point light using a light volume?

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering, lighting, deferred-rendering

### Position reconstruction

I want to verify that this is a valid method and I'm not overlooking something.

I am using a spherical mesh which I am using to only render the portion of the screen that the light overlaps. I rendering only the back-faces if the depth is greater or equal the depth buffer [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14419722/2507444).

To reconstruct the camera space position of a fragment I am taking the vector from the camera space fragment on the light volume, normalizing it, and scaling it by the **linear depth** from my gbuffer (which is stored as a **32 bit float**). This is sort of a hybrid of the methods discussed [here (using linear depth)](http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/reconstructing-position-from-depth/) and [here (spherical light volumes)](http://www.catalinzima.com/xna/tutorials/deferred-rendering-in-xna/point-lights/).

[image: position_reconstruction]

---

### Banding

The reason I ask is because the results I get from deferred vs forward for light attenuation are different.

**Deferred**
[image: deferred]

**Forward**
[image: forward]

Attenuation is linked to my camera space position as I calculate attenuation as follows:

```
vec3 light_dir_to = curr_light.camera_space_position - surface_pos_cam;
float light_dist_sq = dot(light_dir_to, light_dir_to);

float light_attenuation_factor = 1.0f - ((1.0f / (curr_light.radius * curr_light.radius)) * light_dist_sq);
light_attenuation_factor = clamp(light_attenuation_factor, 0.0f, 1.0f);
light_attenuation_factor = pow(light_attenuation_factor, curr_light.falloff);
```

The difference isn't super noticeable in these instances, but the instance I try to scale the light (ex. raise it to a power to make it fade out faster), the effects become immediately apparent.

**light_atten = pow(light_atten, 2.0f)**

[image: attenpow2]

My problem may lie elsewhere, but I want to verify that my position reconstruction method isn't flawed in some way I'm overlooking.

---

### EDIT

Posting my gbuffer setup as requested.

```
enum render_targets { e_dist_32f = 0, e_diffuse_rgb8, e_norm_xyz10, e_spec_intens_b8_spec_pow_a8, e_light_rgb8, num_rt };
//...
GLint internal_formats[num_rt] = {  GL_R32F, GL_RGBA8, GL_RGB10_A2, GL_RGBA8, GL_RGBA8 };
GLint formats[num_rt]          = {   GL_RED,  GL_RGBA,     GL_RGBA,  GL_RGBA,  GL_RGBA };
GLint types[num_rt]            = { GL_FLOAT, GL_FLOAT,    GL_FLOAT, GL_FLOAT, GL_FLOAT };
for(uint i = 0; i < num_rt; ++i)
{
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _render_targets[i]);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internal_formats[i], _width, _height, 0, formats[i], types[i], nullptr);
}
// Separate non-linear depth buffer used for depth testing
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _depth_tex_id);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, _width, _height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);
```

**NOTE:** This issue occurs on planar surfaces that have one normal for the whole surface, thus this cannot be a loss of precision with normals.

---

### FINAL EDIT - SOLUTION

It appears as though this method is in-fact valid (as mentioned by GuyRT). The banding issue appears to be coming from how I am doing gamma correction.

For my forward renderer I only have one loop over 8 lights (I don't do multiple passes, 1 pass only), and I apply gamma correction right after the lighting calculations.

For my deferred renderer I do all lighting calculations, post-processing, etc., then convert to gamma. The issue here is that I:

1. Do my lighting calculations in linear RGB space
2. Store it in a texture in RGB space **(with only 8 bits of precision)**
3. When lighting is done, gamma correct the value and copy it to the back buffer.

For example, let's say the lighting calculations for two fragments have the final values 1/255 (~0.003) and 2/255 (~0.007) in sRGB space (as presented in the end). These values in RGB space are (1/255)^2.2 = ~0.000006 and (2/255)^2.2 = ~0.00002. When these values are stored to my lighting accumulating texture, they are both stored as the same value, 0. This is the cause of the banding.

Converting my lighting accumulation texture to **GL_R11F_G11F_B10F** has yielded results that are very close to my forward renderer. The answers for these two questions helped me once I found that gamma was the issue: [sRGB textures. Is this correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10348719/2507444) and [When to call glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11386809/2507444).

The final result with a "falloff" of 4.0

[image: final_result]

---

### EXTRA RESOURCE

I just found out this effect is called "Gamma Banding", which makes sense. This [website has some useful charts](http://www.graphics.cornell.edu/~westin/gamma/gamma.html) and [this video has a nice numerical walkthrough](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs291/l-124106597/e-176585831/m-176585832).

Comment: How are you storing normals? I have seen banding like that using `RGBA8` format (8 bits are not enough precision for smoothly changing surfaces close up). Try storing them as `GL_RGB10_A2`.

Comment: GuyRT's suggestion sounds spot on, I was thinking that you are losing precision somewhere and that would be an obvious place to lose precision.  The other, I could think of, would be using medium or low precision in the shader.  Post up your g buffer construction and shader code and we can confirm that.

Comment: Added my gbuffer configuration. I actually did run into the normal issue and resolved it [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295120/deferred-rendering-with-opengl-experiencing-heavy-pixelization-near-lit-boundar/22295121#comment33932410_22295121). I also added a note that this cannot be normals as the screenshots provided are of planar surfaces with a single normal for the whole surface.

Comment: @Goz What do you mean by using medium or low precision? A quick search turns up precision qualifiers (lowp, mediump, and highp), but the GLSL 1.40 spec says they mean nothing (same with all I get when I search for them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a bit of tweaking, I think your method is valid and feasible.

This looks very much like the same artefact discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295120/deferred-rendering-with-opengl-experiencing-heavy-pixelization-near-lit-boundar/22295121#comment33932410_22295121). It is caused by a loss of precision in your g-buffer normals. The solution in that case was to use the `GL_RGB10_A2` format to store normals.

If you're interested, there is quite a thorough a discussion of alternative representations for g-buffer normals here: http://aras-p.info/texts/CompactNormalStorage.html, although is is a bit old, so ALU/bandwidth trade-offs might be different today. Also, I think he makes a (quite common) mistake in his discussion of view-space normals, the z-component of which *can* be negative.

Comment: That's actually a question I asked about a week ago. I have changed my normals to RGB10_A2 and it resolved that issue (which only appeared near light boundaries on curved surfaces). What sets this apart is that it happens on a completely flat surface (a planar wall) that has the same normal throughout the entire surface, thus it cannot bee the normals.

Comment: Sorry - I interpreted the pictures as being of smooth round surfaces, and didn't realize you were the same Peter Clark who asked the other question :-). So the gradations in illumination are all caused by light attenuation? You could try increasing the bit-depth of all your `GL_RGBA8` textures to `GL_RGB16` (I'm not quite sure how you are using them) one-by-one to see if and when the banding disappears.

Comment: No worries :), I should have specified along side the screenshots. I'm not sure that increasing the bit depth of my textures is the solution here (given that others have used these depths just fine). Is there any more information I can provide that would be useful? I'm always tempted to put a ton of code and info in my questions but am afraid I'll scare people off with a wall of text so I try to keep what I provide to a minimum.

Comment: Also, I'm going to try using a method that I know for sure for position reconstruction. If that doesn't work I'll accept this as the answer (as it appears my method does work), and then I'll ask another question specifically about the banding if I can't figure it out (since this question was specifically about my method of reconstructing position). If it does work, then I (more or less) know the issue is somewhere with my position reconstruction.

Comment: Actually, I just got my deferred renderer and forward renderer to have the exact same output (horrible banding) by adjusting where I do gamma correction. I'm not trying to adjust it the other way so they have have the same desirable outcome. I had a feeling gamma correction was playing a role in this (I'm still a little fuzzy on it).

Comment: Edited question with my final outcome, it was loss of precision due to storing un-gamma corrected textures in 8 bits before re-gamma correcting them. Your idea of increasing the bit depth definitely worked to combat this.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Interesting that it had to do with gamma correction. I've only recently tried to make my renderer gamma-correct and I'm still not sure I'm doing it right (specifically how it interacts with the tone mapping I do from 16-bit HDR to the final framebuffer).